# Unicode characters in function URL

Tags: aws-lambda

I have this lambda function that works as expected:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = 'Hello {} !'.format(event['rawQueryString'])
    return { 
        'message' : message
    }
```

I get a function URL like this...

https://2ku5vw336655hiomtcogv4sopm0bpqdo.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/?world

And it returns:

> {"message":"Hello world !"}

---

The only problem is that unicode characters are not processed correctly in URL. For e.g.

[https://2ku5vw336655hiomtcogv4sopm0bpqdo.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/?भारत](https://2ku5vw336655hiomtcogv4sopm0bpqdo.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/?%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4)

does not return:

> {"message":"Hello भारत !"}

It returns:

> {"message":"Hello %E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4 !"}

How do I return the correct unicode characters in Lambda?

---

I tried this, but the same results:

```
    return {'statusCode': 200, 'headers': { "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"}, 'body': json.dumps(message)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `urllib.parse.unquote` to decode URL-encoded strings , for your reference check this https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

```
import json
import urllib.parse

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    raw_query_string = event['rawQueryString']
    print("raw",raw_query_string)
    decoded_query_string = urllib.parse.unquote(raw_query_string)
    print("dec",decoded_query_string)
    message = 'Hello {} !'.format(decoded_query_string)
    
    response = {
        'message': message
    }
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': { "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
        'body': json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False)
    }
```

Comment: can i have your input string?

Comment: That glitch was because of 3 seconds limit of lambda. Once I increased it, the problem was solved.